# google web fonts in firefox 7.0.1

Tags: webfonts, firefox7

I have a problem to load the google web fonts on firefox

```
body, input, select, textarea, h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Condensed",sans-serif !important;
}
```

[image: Google Web fonts problem Firefox 7.0.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Google Web Fonts. An internal configuration change broke serving of one of the headers needed for reliable operation in Firefox and IE9+. The fix is propagating now and it should be working soon.

Thanks for reporting the issue!

(I'm an engineer on the Google Web Fonts team, found this in a twitter search trying to investigate how deep the breakage went)